# vb.net identify keyword in simple lexical analyser

Tags: regex, vb.net, lexical-analysis

I have a vb.net regex which I am using to identify operators in a simple `z + x` sum. How can I identify keywords in the given expression with the use of lexical analysis?

My current code:

```
Dim input As String = txtInput.Text
Dim symbol As String = "([-+*/])"
Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, symbol)

For Each match As String In substrings
    lstOutput.Items.Add(match) '<-- Do I need to add a string here to identify the regular expression?
Next
```

---

```
input: z + x
```

This is what I want to happen in the output

```
z - keyword
+ - operator
x - keyword
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following update to your code (as a Console project):

- `operators` contains a string that you can include in your `Regex` pattern and also refer to later
- in the loop, check if `operators` contains `match` meaning that the match is an operator
- anything else is a keyword

So here's the code:

```
Dim input As String = "z+x"
Dim operators As String = "-+*/"
Dim pattern As String = "([" & operators & "])"
Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
For Each match As String In substrings
    If operators.Contains(match) Then
        Console.WriteLine(match & " - operator")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(match & " - keyword")
    End if
Next
```